# Are ASP.NET controller classes instantiated once at startup or every time an endpoint is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get a simple client/server application running using ASP.NET and Angular. I've got some functionality working that allows the client to make calls to the server via POST and to have data returned to it, which is then displayed to the user via Angular.

The application itself is going to be a chatroom application. One of the things I have just been trying to get working is for the user to maintain a temporary list of users that have "logged" into the chatroom. Eventually I'll get a database working for more persistent storage but for now storage at run-time will be enough.

I have a `MessageController` class that contains a `List<string> _userList` object which I intended to use to store my list of temporary usernames, and a POST method that the user can use to register their username to the server.

```
public class MessageController : Controller
    {
        private List<string> _userlist;

        public MessageController()
        {
            _userlist = new List<string>();
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("")]
        public string Post([FromBody]Message msg)
        {
            if (!_userlist.Contains(msg.User))
            {
                _userlist.Add(msg.User);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine, and the username can be added to the list with no issues. However if I attempt to call the method a second time I was surprised to find that my Arraylist contained 0 elements. It seems as though the previous username stored in the Arraylist had been lost.

The only explanation for this I can think of is that the Arraylist had been re-instantiated, losing its previously stored data. This was surprising as I assumed that when I ran my server the controller classes would be instantiated once at startup and then held in memory ready for them to be accessed whenever a call to an endpoint is made. Rather it seems that the controller class is instantiated each time an endpoint is called, rather than once at startup. Am I correct by assuming this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they get re-instantiated every time. HTTP applications are **stateless** by design. Every time you make a new request to the server it's like (with, in the case of the ASP.NET framework, a couple of minor exceptions) like you have never run the code before. The server basically has no memory of the previous activity.

It also has no idea whether you're actually going to make any further requests, or how long it will be until you do, so keeping a copy of all instantiated classes in memory for every single user would be hugely inefficient.

If you want to keep data in between requests in order to maintain state, then you need to store it somewhere. if it's permanent or semi-permanent, then consider storage such as a database or data file. If it's just being kept for the duration of the user's session, then use the ASP.NET Session.

Comment: Perfectly explanation, thank you. I had completely forgotten the statelessness of HTTP. I'll have to get a DB set up instead.